# Is there a way to limit a query based on the result of another in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, limit

So I have a query that I'm using but I want to use the count of the first query in my limit of my 2nd query, is that possible? For example

```
 SELECT 
       Round(0.07 * Count(*), 0)          AS number_required
FROM   trinkets t
       LEFT JOIN orders o
              ON p.order_id = o.id
WHERE  o.trinket_id IN ( 27 )
       AND t.valid_from >= '2022-01-01'
       AND t.valid_from <= '2022-01-31'
```

So I get a number in this first query and I want to use it like this.

```
SELECT
  Rand() AS 'random',
  t.order_id,
  t.serial_number,
  t.valid_from,
  t.valid_till AS 'valid_to',
  comp.org_name AS 'subject_org',
FROM
  trinkets t
  LEFT JOIN orders o ON t.order_id = o.id
  LEFT JOIN companies comp ON o.company_id = comp.id
WHERE
  t.valid_from >= '2022-01-01'
  AND (
    o.status = 3
    AND o.reason IN (6, 11)
  )
  AND o.trinket_id = 27
ORDER BY
  random ASC
limit number_required
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a variable and use it in the second piece of code:

```
SET @number_required = (SELECT ROUND(0.07 * COUNT(*), 0) AS number_required
                        FROM   trinkets t
                        LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.order_id = o.id
                        WHERE o.trinket_id IN ( 27 )
                        AND t.valid_from >= '2022-01-01'
                        AND t.valid_from <= '2022-01-31')
```

**Note:** Call it as `@number_required` not `number_required`

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ?
>   placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using    integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

So you can't use expressions or subqueries or anything like that.

You could run your first query, fetch the result into a variable, and then use that variable in the second query.