# Is there a way to limit a query based on the result of another in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, sql-limit

I'm searching for something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857245/is-there-a-way-to-limit-a-query-based-on-the-result-of-another-in-mysql), but for `sqlite3`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [SELECT/The LIMIT clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#the_limit_clause):

> Any scalar expression may be used in the LIMIT clause, so long as it
> evaluates to an integer or a value that can be losslessly converted to
> an integer...

You can use directly the integer result of a subquery in the `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
ORDER BY id
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2);
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GGZlRE24).